# Gridview get column values- On button click

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview in asp.net application. All the data has been populated.
In a button click (Not in gridview events) I want to get all the particular column values.
I preferred getting item by item. So I tried below way.

```
String columnValue1=Gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
String columnValue2=Gridview1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Text;
String columnValue3=Gridview1.Rows[2].Cells[0].Text;
```

My gridview code is this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
DataRow dr = null; 
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string))); 
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string))); 
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string))); 
dr = dt.NewRow(); dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
dr["Column1"] = string.Empty; 
dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
dr["Column3"] = string.Empty; 
dt.Rows.Add(dr); //Store the DataTable in ViewState 
ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt; 
Gridview1.DataSource = dt; 
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

---

And when I bind the Gridview data to datatable after adding data to controls it returns empty for controls. Can anyone suggest me to solve this issue.

Comment: How is this first column declared?

Comment: It is a textbox type column added to gridview.

Comment: your question doesn't describe problem correctly ?  How do you want t0 show data on which button click? include Html code also ? In which event you have added above code ? Do you want to access this using client side or server side code?

Comment: I want to get data from this button click. <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem

if Gridview columns are label then

```
    Label lb;
    for (int i = 0; i < Gridview1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        lb= Gridview1.Rows[0].FindControl("Column1") as Label;
        columnValue1 = lb.Text;

    }
```